# How does AQS handle interrupts

Tags: java, java-8, interrupt, java.util.concurrent

When a node is queued for a lock, Another thread interrupts him, He would spin once and then cancel the break and rehang himself, It's like it's never interrupted.

According to my understanding, he should cancel the lock acquisition, but now it seems that it is not so. When his previous node releases the lock, he will still grab the lock as if it has never been interrupted, who can tell me why?
Version is JDK8

```
    final boolean acquireQueued(final Node node, int arg) {
        boolean failed = true;
        try {
            boolean interrupted = false;
            for (;;) {
                final Node p = node.predecessor();
                if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                    setHead(node);
                    p.next = null; // help GC
                    failed = false;
                    return interrupted;
                }
                if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                    parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                    interrupted = true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (failed)
                cancelAcquire(node);
        }
    }


    private final boolean parkAndCheckInterrupt() {
        LockSupport.park(this);
        return Thread.interrupted();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you rephrase your question, possibly giving more context info? I'm having problem understanding what exactly are you asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is, When the Thread is woken up from the block, thread.interrupted () is used to clear the interrupted state, and if the lock is not obtained, the Thread is suspended again. According to my understanding, it should enter cancelAcquire method, but I did not find the entrance, can you understand what I mean? I'm sorry, my English is not very good

Answer (score 0):

In your code the thread can leave that infinite `for(;;)` loop only in one way - after it fulfills condition from the `if(p == head && tryAcquire(arg))` - because it's the only `return` statement, you also don't have any breaks.

However, you said that "lock is not obtained", which means the Thread has to continue execution of what is in this for loop, which means executing second if (that suspends thread again).

When you have a construct

```java
try {
  // some code
}finally{
 // finally execution
}
```

The code in the `finally` block will execute only after the execution leaves `try` block (either normally or due to exception).

Comment: Yeah, so when a thread is interrupted, According to the source of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer, he will try again to get a lock, and then continue to hang, so he couldn't enter the cancelAcquire method, then how can I cancel the acquiring a lock? Interrupt means to cancel the lock acquisition, but looking at the source code, it will continue to acquire the lock until it succeeds, then enter the finally method, and will not execute cancelAcquire. This is where I get confused.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I think I understand. For exclusive locks, Doug Lea offer three ways to get them, "acquireQueued,doAcquireInterruptibly,doAcquireNanos", two of them support interrupts, and the method I'm asking doesn't support interrupts, and the author also says in the notes, "Acquires in exclusive uninterruptible mode for thread already in queue. Used by condition wait methods as well as acquire.". So, he's not in favor of interruptions. The finally method was added out of caution. However, the cancelAcquire method is almost never entered.

Answer (score 0):

The method is not support interrupt， you can review `doAcquireInterruptibly`